# SQL 2005: Backup database but ignore FTI Catalog

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005, full-text-catalog

Folks,
    Apologies for aksing what might be a very simple question, but can I backup a database and ignore the databases FTI catalog?

These backups will be restored to a different server and the FTI Catalog isn't necessarry.

Thanks
BW

**UPDATE**

Folks, I eventually gave up on this and came at the problem from a completely different direction, one which doesn't involve backing up and restoring the database.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you drop the full text catalog first.  If you try to fake it out you will get [errors like this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923355)